# How avoid overlay of dimmer over dropdown menu Semantic UI React?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a drop-down menu that activates a component in which a dimmer is performed while loading the data.

However, when the drop-down menu is activated, this is dimmer by the component mentioned.

```js
<Fragment>
        <Menu color="blue" inverted size="large">
          <Dropdown item text="Malla Vial">
            <Dropdown.Menu >
              <Dropdown.Header>Reportes Malla Vial <Icon name="road" /></Dropdown.Header>
              {reportesMV.map(clase => (<Dropdown.Item key={clase} onClick={this.handleItemClick} name={clase} >{clase}</Dropdown.Item>))}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
          <Dropdown item text="Infraestructura Asociada" >
            <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Header>Reportes Infraestructura Asociada <Icon name="chain" /></Dropdown.Header>
              {reportesIA.map(clase => (<Dropdown.Item key={clase} onClick={this.handleItemClick} name={clase} >{clase}</Dropdown.Item>))}
            </Dropdown.Menu>
          </Dropdown>
        </Menu>

        {activeItem === reportesMV[0] && <JerarquiaEstado /> }
        {activeItem === reportesMV[1] && <JerarquiaSuperficie /> }
        {activeItem === reportesMV[2] && <LongitudMallaVial tipo="comuna" /> }
        {activeItem === reportesMV[3] && <LongitudMallaVial tipo="barrio" /> }
        {activeItem === reportesIA[3] && <EstadoAndenSeparadorComuna /> }
      </Fragment>
```

JerarquiaEstado Component

```js
<Dimmer.Dimmable dimmed={isFetchingData}>
        <Dimmer inverted active={isFetchingData}>
          {isFetchingData && <Loader inline content="Cargando Datos..." />}
        </Dimmer>
        <Container loading={this.state.isFetching}>
          <NoPrint force>
          <Grid>
```

Comment: Sorry Lucas, but I don't understand what you are asking. Can you try to frame your question a little bit better?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for that. 
What I am trying to do is that the drop-down menu is not affected by the dimmer that is applied to the component shown below.
The situation is seen more clearly in the following image. Thank you.
[link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZng3J6ssajwY8eqb6YrwnXtIUEl6gM5/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

The dimmer has position set to absolute, with top and left set to 0. If those coordinates apply to an element that is not your Dropdown menu, but one of its parents, the dimmer will be overlaying your menu.

From the definition of position: absolute:

> An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor.

Try setting position: relative; on your menu.

It worked for me, and is a much better solution than playing with zIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found that CSS property of dimmer semantic ui was z-index: 1000, then I added a style zIndex: 1001 in "Dropdown.Menu" component to display the menu above the dimmer.

```
    <Menu color="blue" inverted size="large">
      <Dropdown item text="YYY" >
        <Dropdown.Menu style={{ zIndex: 1001 }} >
          <Dropdown.Header>YYY <Icon name="road" /></Dropdown.Header>
          {YYY.map(clase => (<Dropdown.Item key={clase} onClick={this.handleItemClick} name={clase} >{clase}</Dropdown.Item>))}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
      <Dropdown item text="ZZZ" >
        <Dropdown.Menu style={{ zIndex: 1001 }}>
          <Dropdown.Header>ZZZ<Icon name="chain" /></Dropdown.Header>
          {reportesIA.map(clase => (<Dropdown.Item key={clase} onClick={this.handleItemClick} name={clase} >{clase}</Dropdown.Item>))}
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I overwrote the z-index of the dimmer in my index.css file. 990 was sufficient for me. Adjust as needed.

```
.ui.dimmer {
  z-index: 990 !important;
}
```